# TypeError after upgrading to Angular6 in function dealing with nativeElement.setAttribute in component

Tags: angular, unit-testing, error-handling, typeerror, angular6

question!

I've a searchbar component that has a textarea as field for search.
According to quantity of text I search, I increase or decrease the number of rows of the textarea itself.
So I've some operations that deal with the native element of the textarea.
For example this function

**searchbar.ts**

```
focus() {
  if (this.textArea) {
    this.focussed = true;
    this.textArea.nativeElement.setAttribute('rows', this.calcRows());

    // extra part ...
  }
}
```

**searcbar.spec.ts**

```
describe('focus', () => {
  it('should set focussed to true', () => {
    component.focussed = false;
    component.focus();
    expect(component.focussed).toBe(true);
  });

  it('should set the height of the textArea by setting the row to the correct amount', () => {
    spyOn(component.textArea.nativeElement, 'setAttribute');
    spyOn(component, 'calcRows').and.returnValue(2);

    component.focus();
    expect(component.textArea.nativeElement.setAttribute).toHaveBeenCalledWith('rows', 2);
  });
});
```

The tests actually are not failing.
But I display this error and it is referred that I assume they refer not to the test itself, but to the component.

> ERROR: 'ERROR', TypeError: undefined is not a function (evaluating
>   'this.textArea.nativeElement.setAttribute('rows',this.calcRows())')

Any ideas how to fix it?
Thanks in advance

Comment: whats if you log this.textArea?

Comment: and check ```this.textArea.rows = this.calcRows()```

Comment: this is my log ElementRef {nativeElement: textarea.search-input.e2e__query.ng-untouched.ng-pristine.ng-valid}

Comment: Property 'rows' does not exist on type 'ElementRef' if I try to use this code `this.textArea.rows = this.calcRows()`

Comment: ok, then try ```this.textArea.nativeElement.rows = this.calcRows()```

Comment: this last way works! thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try `this.textArea.nativeElement.rows = this.calcRows()`